# Deleting an user in Azure AD through graph in Express API

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an API through which I want to delete an user in Azure AD.

The API is registered, and has the following application scope to access graph:

- User.ReadWrite.All (Which according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) should be enough)

Additionally, the API has the default roles that are assigned upon creation, that is:

- Attribute assignment administrator
- Attribute assignment reader
- Cloud application administrator
- Reports reader

^ Not sure if these matters though - Nonetheless, I'm not sure that I can assign any additional roles under the free tier.

Anyway, I'm calling graph as follows:

```
module.exports.deleteUserById = async (objectId) => {
    const ccrRequest = {
        scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
    }
    const accessToken = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(ccrRequest)

    const options = {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken.accessToken}`, 'Content-Type': "application/json" },
    }

    return await fetch(graphUsers() + `/${objectId}`, options)
}
```

The above should work, however when I'm attempting to delete any given user, the call returns an error:

> code:'Authorization_RequestDenied' message:'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.'

Comment: Other than your `socpe` do you have `User.ReadWrite.All` Application permission on azure portal? and confirmed that you have accpeted admin consent for that. Must have `Global Administrator` and `User Administrator` to execute delete operation/

Comment: These roles are not enough to execute `delete operation` Attribute assignment `administrator
Attribute assignment reader
Cloud application administrator
Reports reader`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron yes the application scope is added and granted. I may suspect that I would need to add 'User Administrator' to my service principal - But I can't seem to add that anywhere? Is it a limitation of the free tier azure ad?

Comment: I'm not sure about free trail you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions) , but either  `Global Administrator` or `User Administrator` is mandatory for this operation.

Comment: That validates my initial thoughts - I'm just in doubt how to add the role to the principal. 
When I go `Enterprise applications -> principal name -> Roles and administrators` there is no option to add another role.

Comment: Global administrator

Comment: Please refer to this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron this is app roles which is completely different. App-roles are mostly used for UX purposes and does not have anything to do with the AD roles

Comment: Alright, could you please check if you can execute this operation from postman?

Comment: It’s exactly the same ☺️

Answer (score 1):

You must have a **Global administrator** or **User administrator** role assignment to delete users in your organization. **Global admins** can delete any users including other admins. User administrators can delete any non-admin users, Helpdesk administrators and other User administrators. For more information, see [Administrator role permissions in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference)

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory)

To assign particular role to users follow these steps

**1)** Sign in to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) or [Azure AD admin center](https://aad.portal.azure.com/).

**2)** Select **Azure Active Directory > Roles and administrators** to see the list of all available roles.

[image]

**3)** Select a role to see its assignments.
To help you find the role you need, use **Add filters** to filter the roles.

**4)** Select **Add assignments** and then select the **users** you want to assign to this role.

[image]

**5)** Select **Add** to assign the role.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal)